# Google plus one code as inline block

Tags: inline, html, google-plus-one, css

I get Google plus one code as follows. This shows button well.

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-href="http://www.example.com"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

When i put some HTML after this code, +1 code creates new line, and following elements apeear in net line. I tried to change "`div`" with "`span`", i tried to add "`style="display: inline"`" to "`div`" tag. But none of them worked.

How can i change this code snippet so following elements won't be in new line?

Thank you.

Comment: Show the HTML that this script injects in your page and the lines of HTML after it...

Comment: Following elements are not special.  One <img> that links to another blog page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change, to my knowledge, what Google is injecting in your page but you can style it appropriately with `CSS` on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div tag to place it in line with facebook button... Have a look...

```
<div style="margin-top: 11px;"><li class='g-plusone' data-size='tall'/></div></div>
```

Before this you need to run a script which is mandatory:

```
<script async='' defer='' src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js'></script>
```

This will work for you.